# In emacs, is wrangler is better choice than distel for erlang?

Tags: erlang

In last week, I know `'wrangler'` exists for the first time. From the introduction, it is better than `distel`. 
If you use both types of extension already, could you tell me is it worth replacing `distel` with `wrangler`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wrangler](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/forse/wrangler/doc/overview-summary.html) is *not* an Erlang mode for Emacs.
It's a [refactoring tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) for Erlang which happens to run in Emacs.
You can use it in conjunction with Distel.

Comment: Wrangler brings it's own distel version with it -- so you end up using it, even if you don't have it installed seperatly.